# What uniform is General Redvers Henry Buller VC GCB GCMG wearing in this colored photo?

Tags: military, identification, united-kingdom, uniform, fashion

Colored studio photograph circa 1900 of General Redvers Henry Buller VC GCB GCMG in uniform with decorations. Is it that of a General in the Kings Royal Rifle Corps?  Confirmation or other identification would be much appreciated!

From [Wikipedia: General Redvers Henry Buller VC GCB GCMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redvers_Buller)

[image]

My apologies: I dragged and dropped the image for my original post. It showed on my screen, but obviously did not carry over to the post.

Comment: Is it possible that you meant to refer to the colorized photo on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redvers_Buller#/media/File:VCRedversHenryBuller.jpg)  If so, I'm happy to include a link in the question.

Comment: After the edit it is still unclear to me which image you are talking about.   Are you asking if the Wikipedia illustration for Buller is in fact a picture of Buller?  Or if the uniform shown there is a Rifles uniform?

Comment: Hi. I am asking for verification of the uniform in the color studio portrait of Buller - the first image on the website.

Comment: Superficially, yes. The funny cap with its plume and badge match pictures a google search for Royal Rifles brings up, illustrated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Green_Jackets .  The pic on http://rgjmuseum.co.uk/photo-archive-item/ensign-heathcote/ shows embroidery decoration consistent with your picture. The overall color is consistent with what I see on a google search for "royal rifle corps dress uniforms" brings up. Is there some particular point you are interested in?

Comment: There is a color called "Rifle Green" ( https://www.crispedge.com/color/414833 ), the name of the color of the Royal Rifle Corps uniforms. Which, to my eye, matches the color seen in your picture.

Answer (score 4):

There is a version of this picture that bears the description:

> [image: Colonel]
>
> Right Hon. Sir Redvers Buller, V.C., G.C.B., etc.
> Commanding in Natal
> In the Uniform of Colonel Commandant, King's Royal Rifle Corps

Searching just for the uniform of that unit then lists Buller as a prominent 'search-hit', like [Original Rifle CORPS Uniform Pics](http://www.victorianstrollers.co.uk/stevesuniforms/riflecorps.html), and reveals this illustration:

[King's Royal Rifle Corps, Officers and Rifleman 1904](https://www.britishempire.co.uk/forces/armyuniforms/britishinfantry/krrc1904.htm):

> [image]

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. The caption relating to 'Colonel Commandant, King's Royal Rifle Corps' under the image would appear to 'nail' it.